# Oracle SQL Basic Query

Tags: oracle

I try to solve this query.

Write and test SQL to create a list of customers who have never made a  purchase.

I create like this

```
enter code here

SELECT DISTINCT CU.CustomerID
FROM  DD_Customers CU,DD_Orders O,DD_OrderLine OL
WHERE  CU.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
AND     O.OrderID = O.OrderID
AND ol.quantitypurchased > 1;
```

I do not know how to express "never made a  purchase " on query

DD_Customers

CustomerID, CustomerFname, CustomerLname,

12345

12346

12347

12348

12349

**12350**

so I created CustomerID 12350 for this query, which dose not show up in DD_Orders

DD_Orders

OrderID,DATEPURCHASED,CustomerID,SALESMANID,METHODOFDELIVERY

DD_ORDERLINE

OrderID,PRODUCTID,ORDERDATE,Quantity,Price

How can I do this query

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM DD_Customers
WHERE CustomerId NOT IN (
    SELECT O.CustomerId
    FROM DD_Orders O
        JOIN DD_OrderLine OL ON O.OrderID = OL.OrderID
    WHERE ol.quantitypurchased > 1
)
```

Comment: FYI, you could also do a `GROUP BY` and `SUM`, but this is likely more performant, since it only needs to find one nozero record with that customer id, rather than actually summing all the records by group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dd_customers (
  customer_id NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE dd_orders (
  customer_id NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO dd_customers VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO dd_customers VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO dd_customers VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO dd_orders VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO dd_orders VALUES (3);

SELECT DISTINCT ddc.customer_id
  FROM dd_customers ddc
    LEFT JOIN dd_orders ddo ON (ddc.customer_id = ddo.customer_id)
HAVING COUNT(ddo.customer_id) = 0
GROUP BY ddc.customer_id
;
```

Comment: Having both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CU.CustomerID
FROM  DD_Customers CU,DD_Orders O,DD_OrderLine OL
WHERE  CU.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
AND     O.OrderID = OL.OrderID
GROUP BY CU.CustomerID HAVING sum(ol.quantitypurchased) = 0;
```

Comment: Isn't it custom to thank by grading the answer? ;) (the up/down buttons on the left)